# Extending multiple classes in scss file not working

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, sass, adminlte

I'm using [AdminLte](https://github.com/ColorlibHQ/AdminLTE) in my project, and in a `html` page I have:

```
<aside class="main-sidebar sidebar-dark-primary elevation-4">
<aside>
```

Everything works fine.

I created a custom `scss` file to support multiple tenants, imported `scss` files and I created then following style:

```
@import '_adminlte/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
@import '_adminlte/build/scss/adminlte.raw';

.tenant-sidebar {
     @extend .main-sidebar, .sidebar-dark-primary, .elevation-4
}
```

so then I change my `aside` tag to:

```
<aside class="tenant-sidebar">
<aside>
```

However, doing this applies only the `main-sidebar` and `elevation-4` classes. The `sidebar-dark-primary` class is not applied.

Is there a reason why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR: 
`.sidebar-dark-primary` class is empty in the adminlte.css

As I saw it, `sidebar-dark-primary` css class doesn't have any style in the generated css file. It's only purpose is to wrap the child elements stylings like this: 
`.sidebar-dark-primary .nav-sidebar.nav-legacy > .nav-item > .nav-link.active` 
So when you `@extend` this class, there won't be any related stylings.

Comment: So if it's a class that I cannot extend, how can I add it to my customer 'tenant-sidebar' as the scss file instead of in the html page?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [SASS Docs on @extend](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/extend#disallowed-selectors),

```css
.tenant-sidebar {
     @extend .main-sidebar, .sidebar-dark-primary, .elevation-4
}
```

basically means extend this selector: `.main-sidebar.sidebar-dark-primary.elevation-4`

---

I would give this a try instead:

```css
.tenant-sidebar {
     @extend .main-sidebar;
     @extend .sidebar-dark-primary;
     @extend .elevation-4;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: Are the definitions of `.main-sidebar`, `.sidebar-dark-primary` and `.elevation-4` in the available in the context (eg by being in the same scss file or imported to it via `@import`)?

Comment: Update the question with more details of the framework I'm using and the `@import` lines.